# Iam facing issue with iMessage icon

Tags: ios, png, imessage

We are facing error/issue while we submitting app on app store. please check the error screenshot: Error screenshot This error occurs when validating. Below is the i Message icon and its info which we used iMessage app icon Image

The error message is "The bundle doesn't contain an iMessage icon. iMessage app icons must be 120x90 pixels in .png format"

Is it an xcode issue OR issue with the image?

Comment: I'm confused, where is the issue you're seeing? What are you trying to do?

Comment: That doesn’t really answer the question haha. This question is super unspecific, I have no idea what you’re trying to do

Comment: Can you update your question with steps to reproduce your problem and what you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: Just edit your question with the relevant info haha. Sort, terse questions are very difficult to answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218020/the-bundle-doesnt-contain-an-imessage-icon-imessage-app-icons-must-be-120x90-p